# Axios code not running after `.then`

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I am new to react/nodejs/express/javascript and have encountered the following problem:

I want to get a number, then post that number + 1, then I want to create a new js object using that number(`newFreshId`) and I want to add it to add that event to my `schedulerData`. When I try running the code, I can get and post to `/api/num`, but I everything after the `.then(function(response) {` doesnt appear to run.

I wanted to do this sequentially, so I used `.then` after every task so that I would not have encountered a problem.

I also tried to remove all the `.then`s in favor of a while loop that waits for the value to change. This also did not work.

CODE:

CLIENT:

```
this.newEvent = (schedulerData, slotId, slotName, start, end, type, item) => {
    let newFreshId = 0;
    let newEvent = {}
    axios.get("/api/num").then(function(response) {
        newFreshId = response.data[0] + 1;

        // console.log(newFreshId);
    }).then(function() {
        axios.post("/api/num", {
            id: newFreshId
        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response)
            // handle success
            newEvent = {
                id: newFreshId,
                title: this.state.title,
                start: start,
                end: end,
                resourceId: slotId
            };
            schedulerData.addEvent(newEvent);
            this.setState({
                viewModel: schedulerData
            });

            // while(JSON.stringify(newEvent) === '{}'){
            //   console.log('waiting')
            // }

            console.log(newEvent)
            schedulerData.addEvent(newEvent);

            console.log(newEvent)
            this.setState({
                viewModel: schedulerData
            });
        })
    })
};
```

SERVER:

```
app.get('/api/num', function(req, res) {
    //console.log(require('./number.json'))
    var fs  = require('fs')
    fs.readFile('./number.json', {encoding:   'utf-8'}, function(err,data){
    if (!err) {
        //console.log('received data: ' + JSON.parse(data));
        res.json(JSON.parse(data))
    } else {
        console.log(err);
    }})
})

app.post('/api/num', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.body.id
    var fs = require('fs');

    fs.writeFileSync("./number.json", "[ "+id+" ]", function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        res.status(200)
    })
})
```

Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Try adding a `catch` to see if there are any errors.

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but where do I put the catch? In the server or client?

Comment: After your `.then`s

Comment: No errors... It worked fine

Comment: Having same exact issue.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced an issue where I wasn't able to run the .then() or .catch() code

```js
const fetch = async() => {
  axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.24.0/axios.min.js"></script>
```

All I did was add **async** to the function and it started working

Answer (score 0):

`fs.writeFileSync` doesn't have a callback, so the function you're adding never gets executed: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options

This means the response is never sent back to the client, and the axios promise is never resolved.

Try using `fs.writeFile` with a callback: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

It's also a good idea to send a response in the case of an error, too.

```
app.post('/api/num', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.body.id
    var fs = require('fs');

    fs.writeFile("./number.json", "[ "+id+" ]", function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(200)
        }
        res.status(200)
    })
})
```

Finally, though it wouldn't help you in this situation, you should add a `.catch` to the very tail end of your axios chain.  Any errors that take place in the promise chain will wind up there.

An example:

```
axios.get(specs).then(someFunction).catch(e => console.error(e));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it did not work. I'm gonna try fs.writeFileSync without a callback, maybe that would work

Comment: Cool cool . Be sure to check your console for errors in the browser, and add that `catch`.

Comment: I'd differentiate your api endpoints (`'/api/num1'`, `'/api/num2'`), and put a console log at the start, to ensure the correct one is being hit.  Are you sure execution is even getting to the `fs.writeFileSync`?

And as an aside, your probably don't actually want to hold up the response while you write a file, in the real world.  This is fine for testing, but I'd respond right away in your app, then asynchronously write the file after res.status(200).

Comment: Ok, so now I am getting a 500 error. `Error: "Request failed with status code 500"` Here is a the response `Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/nump from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3001 (ECONNRESET).`

Answer (score 0):

for me I was facing the same issue and I figured it out that because I'm using some redirection after making a post request

```
window.location.href = "/{redirect to some rout}"
```

this makes the console change immediately so I couldn't see the then response unless I removed the redirection.

Answer (score -1):

const axios = require('axios').default;

use it like this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).